# How to animate views within each ListView items?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

[image: Google+ app screenshot]

If you have used the Google+ app on Android you must have noticed the comments on posts are animated to show comments one by one using a **fadeIn and fadeOut** animation on each ListView item.

I want to achieve this type of animation for certain views like TextView, etc within each of my ListView item.

I can achieve the fadeIn and fadeOut animation part but the problem is where do I put the animation code for it to **work independently for each inflated ListView item**.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do this in ListView also. Please post more info on what element you want to animate and based on what criteria? This is important to tell where you need to put the code.

Comment: I want to have two TextViews in each ListView item. One would fadeIn lets say "7:45 pm" on app start, then after 2-3 secs the TextView would fadeOut and a new TextView saying "1 hr 45 mins left" would fadeIn in the place of the older TextView, again after 2-3 secs this new TextView would fadeOut to make way for the initial TextView "7:45 pm". Are you getting my point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use a `BaseAdapter` and put the necessary animation codes in your `getView()` method.

Just inflate the views and start the animations when the views are inflated for the first time. (Hint - when `convertView == null`)

Use the **ViewHolder** pattern to hold each of the elements of the single list item uniquely and start animations no any `View` you need inside each list item.

To start animations, create an animation in XML and start the animation like this,

```
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_up);
                anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                anim.setDuration(500);
                anim.setStartOffset(100);
                anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });

                progress.startAnimation(anim);
```

To give you an idea on how to create animations in XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <alpha
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="5%p" />
</set>
```

You can use an animation set to combine multiple animations together and play them at once.

Please also explore the **Animation API** in greater detail, you will find useful methods like `setRepeatMode()` and `setRepeatCount()` which will help you to achieve the desired result.

Moreover, you do not need two separate TextViews, you can do it using one. Just make proper use of the animation listeners.

Hope it helps.

Comment: There's a problem. The Animation is working fine, however maybe due to view recycling the animation effect is jumping from one list item to another even when there should not be any animation performed on a specific list item. Any solution?

Comment: If the animation is working fine, then what I told should be correct. This kind of problem can only occur if the adapter and the ViewHolder pattern is not implemented correctly.

Comment: I have used ViewHolder pattern and the views are recycled as well. All the values are being assigned correctly, except the Animation. I have tried a lot of things, but nothing works.